# Add Special Symbols to the end of a line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, special-characters

I have a huge file and I know how to add some then at the end or start of line. I've following scenario
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc

And I need to add ") by the end of the line but add only " and missed ). 
Is there someone who could help me to figure it out?

Comment: It was resolved, by using alt+shift+keyDown or keyUp combination at the end of the line and then paste what was required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis in the replacement part:

Find what: `$`
Replace with: `"\)`

At the bottom of pop up box for replacing, change Search Mode to `Regular expression`(no need match newline)